# Using WCF - how to transfer data and get an acknowledgement

Tags: wcf

How to get an acknoledgement message while transferring large amount of data using WCF from once server to another

Comment: The successful completion of the operation _is_ the acknowledgement.

Comment: As John says, if all you want is an acknowledgement then just wait for the completion of the operation.  Otherwise, have a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/491844/A-Beginners-Guide-to-Duplex-WCF

Comment: but how can one be ensured that the data has been successfullly received at the other end. Is MSMQ is the way to accomplish this

Answer (score 0):

If you are considering synchronous communication, a valid response from the server will be acknowledgement of the message delivery, along with all its data.

But when talking about large amount of data you should consider using [Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) so you will reduce memory overhead:

> When you have a large amount of data to transfer, the streaming transfer mode in WCF is a feasible alternative to the default **behavior of buffering** and processing messages in memory in their entirety.